# Preventing buffer overflow in C/C++

Tags: c++, c, buffer-overflow

Many times I have problems with Buffer Overflow.

```
int y[10][10][10];
```

...

```
y[0][15][3] = 8;
```

How can I prevent this problem?
Is there any good tool that can help me?

Comment: You'll get better answers if you make up you're mind about the language you're using. C and C++ are very different languages.

Comment: I wish I could edit comments... should be "your mind" of course.

Comment: @avakar: Just delete your comment and re-add it.

Comment: You don't have an overflow in your example. 10x10x10 = 1000, so you have an array of 1000 ints. Index [0][15][3] is 15*10 + (3+1) = 154th int so you are within bounds.

Comment: I use both C and C++.
The problem is for raw C arrays as in the example.ù

You are right, it is not a buffer overflow on over the whole multidimensional array, but if I define an array as 10x10x10 I don't want to go over the single dimension of the array.
   
    Thanks

      Best Regards

Comment: Yeah Seriously, i dont see a buffer overflow here!

Answer (score 10):

Neil's answer is better in the general case, but if you have a reason for using plain old arrays, you can use functions to get and set the values and also check that you're within the array bounds:

```
#define MAX_INDEX 10

int y[MAX_INDEX][MAX_INDEX][MAX_INDEX];

int get_y(int a, int b, int c)
{
    ASSERT(a >= 0 && a < MAX_INDEX);
    ASSERT(b >= 0 && b < MAX_INDEX);
    ASSERT(c >= 0 && c < MAX_INDEX);
    return y[a][b][c];
}

void set_y(int a, int b, int c, int value)
{
    ASSERT(a >= 0 && a < MAX_INDEX);
    ASSERT(b >= 0 && b < MAX_INDEX);
    ASSERT(c >= 0 && c < MAX_INDEX);
    y[a][b][c] = value;
}
```

...all wrapped up in a class, ideally.

Comment: To nit pick a bit, ASSERT's aren't going to work quite the way you expect in an embedded system(unless you've specifically coded for them). But I would agree in the large

Answer (score 10):

Don't use raw C-style arrays. Instead, use C++ container classes such as std::vector, which have the ability to check for invalid accesses and raise exceptions when they occur.

Also, what you are describing is not really a buffer overflow.

Comment: Many times I code for embedded systems where are only raw arrays allowed.

   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other comments, you might also have a look at the suggestions in this thread, which deals with static code analysis tools:

[C/C++ Free alternative to Lint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/632057/c-c-free-alternative-to-lint)

Answer (score 1):

### Solution at the code level

In C++, one solution is to never use arrays, but C++ containers instead. Vectors, for example, have out of bounds detection if you use at intead of [] for indexing

In C, you should always design your functions such as you give the pointers and the dimension(s) of your arrays, there is no way around it.

### Solution at the tool level

A great tool for checking out of bounds access is valgrind. It works by running your binary unaltered, and can give the precise line where errors occurs if you compile with debug information. Valgrind work on many unix, including mac os x.

Note that valgrind cannot always detect those bad accesses (in your example, assuming it was a real out of bounds access, it would have gonve unnoticed by valgrind because the variable is on the stack, not on the heap).

Comment: Valgrind wouldn't find this one even on the heap, because the access is within the whole of the array (as @qrdl points out in his comment to the question).

Comment: that was the sense of "assuming it was a real out of bounds access"

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically allocate data members from the heap rather than through statically allocated arrays. The former approach has pros and cons with fgets(), the latter approach. While former avoids buffer overflow, it is difficult to program and requires an exacting amount of precision to avoid memory leaks.