# Strange characters appear when using strcat function in C++

Tags: c++, strcat

I am a newbie to C++ and learning from the MSDN C++ Beginner's Guide.

While trying the strcat function it works but I get three strange characters at the 
beginning.

Here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char first_name[40],last_name[40],full_name[80],space[1];
    space[0] = ' ';
    cout << "Enter your first name: ";
    gets(first_name);
    cout << "Enter your last name: ";
    gets(last_name);
    strcat(full_name,first_name);
    strcat(full_name,space);
    strcat(full_name,last_name);
    cout << "Your name is: " << full_name;
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output

```
Enter your first name: Taher
Enter your last name: Abouzeid
Your name is: Y}@Taher Abouzeid
```

I wonder why Y}@ appear before my name ?

Comment: AAAAAH! `gets()` it away from us! It burns us!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array that you are creating is full of random data. C++ will allocate the space for the data but does not initialize the array with known data. The strcat will attach the data to the end of the string (the first '\0') as the array of characters has not been initialized (and is full of random data) this will not be the first character.

This could be corrected by replacing

```
char first_name[40],last_name[40],full_name[80],space[1];
```

with

```
char first_name[40] = {0};
char last_name[40] = {0};
char full_name[80] = {0};
char space[2] = {0};
```

the `= {0}` will set the first element to '\0' which is the string terminator symbol, and c++ will automatically fill all non specified elements with '\0' (provided that at least one element is specified).

Comment: That works with slight modification.
I replaced char space; with char space[2] = {0}; and that works perfect.
Change it in the answer please so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 9):

You aren't initializing full_name by setting the first character to '\0' so there are garbage characters in it and when you strcat you are adding your new data after the garbage characters.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `full_name` isn't being initialized before being appended to.

Change this:

```
strcat(full_name,first_name);
```

to this:

```
strcpy(full_name,first_name);
```

Comment: Also, `space` isn't null terminated.

Comment: True. The `space` array needs to be defined with a size of 2 and initialized with the string `" "` instead of the char `' '`.

Answer (score 1):

You can not see any problem in your test, but your `space` string is also not null-terminated after initializing its only character with `' '`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, you must initialize the data, but have you ever thought about learning the standard c++ library? It is more intuitive sometimes, and probably more efficient.

With  it would be:

```
string full_name=first_name+" "+last_name;
```

and you won't have to bother with terminating null characters. For a reference go to [cplusplus](http://cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

Oh and a full working example so you could understand better (from operator+=):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string name ("John");
  string family ("Smith");
  name += " K. ";         // c-string
  name += family;         // string
  name += '\n';           // character

  cout << name;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `space` text.

The `strcat` function requires a C-style string, which is zero or more characters followed by a null, terminating, character.  So when allocating arrays for C-style strings, you need to allocate one extra character for the terminating null character.

So, your `space array needs to be of length 2, one for the space character and one for the null character.`

Since `space` is constant, you can use a string literal instead of an array:

`const char space[] = " ";`

Also, since you are a newbie, here are some tips:
1.  Declare one variable per line.
This will be easier to modify and change variable types.

2.  Either flush `std::cout`, use `std::endl`, or include a '\n'.
This will flush the buffers and display any remaining text.

3.  Read the C++ language FAQ.
[Click here for the C++ language Frequently Asked Questions (FAQ)](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/)

4. You can avoid C-style string problems by using std::string

5. Invest in Scott Myers **Effective C++** and **More Effective C++** books.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are null-terminated in C and C++ (the strcat function is a legacy of C). This means that when you point to a random memory address (new char[] variables point to a stack address with random content that does not get initialized), the compiler will interpret everything up to the first \0 (null) character as a string (and will go beyond the allocated size if you use pointer arithmetic).

This can lead to very obscure bugs, security issues (buffer overflow exploits) and very unreadable and unmaintainable code. Modern compilers have features that can help with the detection of such issues.

Here is [a good summary of your options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083898/preventing-buffer-overflow-in-c-c).